# Possible timeout during Set-AzureDeployment

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-management-api

I have a Powershell script that executes Set-AzureDeployment. It works fine for a service with 1 role.

However, when I run it for another service with 7 roles, it often fails (not always). All I get back is the message below.

I'm inclined to think this is a timeout in the underlying HttpClient connection. Any thoughts/workarounds?

```
Set-AzureDeployment : An error occurred while sending the request.
At <my script>
+     $setdeployment = Set-AzureDeployment `
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureDeployment], HttpRequestException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.HostedServices.SetAzureDeploymentCommand
```

I found [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/82ed25ce-9ea5-4a6b-af38-38af5a0ccd3a/specifying-timeout-on-setazuredeployment-azure-powershell-cmdlet?forum=windowsazuremanagement) which doesn't have a resolution.

Comment: According to your description and error message, we couldn't find any useful information. I suggest you could post the details arm template and use -debug to get the details error message.